# Selenium: Input into a text field with style="display: none;"

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, display

I've been trying to get selenium to input my username and password into a site and have seen various methods mentioned on other forums none of which have worked for me. Here is what is returned upon inspecting the "username" field on the site:

```
<input type="text" id="curruserelt" value="" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" class="">
```

I tried using the ID method but to no avail, I am trying this xpath method:

```
username = "ajusingt121"
element_enter = findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="curruserelt"]")).sendKeys(username);
element_enter.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/input[1]")).sendKeys(username);
```

But for whatever reason it keeps returning invalid syntax error at the xpath id part.

Whats the best way to tackle this type of form and input data?

Comment: This part of xpath seems incorrect - `By.xpath("//*[@id="curruserelt"]")` instead wrapping the string into double quotes wrap it in single quotes like this - `By.xpath("//*[@id='curruserelt']")` or do vice versa with external double quotes.

Comment: That worked thank you! But it keeps saying that 'findElement' is not defined, the forum didn't mention anything about defining findElement so I'm wondering how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Off course you are mixing Java and Python `findElement` belongs to Java, `find_element_by_xpath()` is belongs to Python.

Comment: I've imported ```from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By``` but still get the ```find_element_by_xpath()``` is not defined in Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) won't be able to send a character sequence in an `<input>` field with `style` attribute set as **`"display: none;"`**.

However, you tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) but your code block is in [java](/questions/tagged/java)

In *Python* you use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="curruserelt"]").send_keys(username)
```

In *Java* you use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="curruserelt"]")).sendKeys(username);
```

> **Note**: However there are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) hacks which can help you to achieve the same.

---

### Update

To send a character sequence to the `<input>` field with you have to remove the `style` attribute which is set as `"display: none;"` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  username = "ajusingt121"
  element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#curruserelt[type='text']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#curruserelt[type='text']").send_keys(username)
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  username = "ajusingt121"
  element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='curruserelt' and @type='text']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", element)
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='curruserelt' and @type='text']").send_keys(username)
  ```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about doing this with javascript within Python?

Comment: Couldn't get the ```find_element_by_xpath``` method to work in Python, no errors it just doesn't seem to input into the field on the page based on that ID I got from inspect element of the username field.

Comment: @mya205 As I said, your desired element to send text would be some other element, at least not this element with `style` attribute set as `"display: none;"`. I can provide you the code but that wouldn't be among the best practices.

Comment: If you could that'd be really helpful because I'm quite lost with how to proceed. When I hit F12 and then click the username field that's what the inspect element showed me, what else should I look for because nothing else appears to be highlighted by the inspect element.

Comment: @mya205 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.